# How to optimise this sql query (inner joins)

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

Is there anyway to optimze this query.It is taking more than 40 seconds to execute.I tried many ways like creating indexes.That helped little.Still query time is too long.

```
 SELECT b.id,
   Count(DISTINCT a.id, c.chapters_id) AS pct,
   Count(DISTINCT e.id)                 AS eCount,
   Count(DISTINCT f.id)                 AS fCount,
   Count(DISTINCT d2.id)                 AS d2Count,
   b.NAME,
   e.NAME,
   e.address2,
   f.NAME,
   d2.is_active
FROM   tableA a
       INNER JOIN tableB b
               ON a.modules_id = b.id
       INNER JOIN tableC c
               ON a.modules_id = c.modules_id
       INNER JOIN tableD d1
               ON d1.id = b.store_users_id 
       INNER JOIN tableD d2
               ON d2.id = a.store_users_id
       INNER JOIN tableE e
               ON e.id = d2.stores_id
       INNER JOIN tableF f
               ON e.city = f.id
WHERE  b.type IN( 1, 2, 4 )
       AND b.organizations_id = 156
       AND b.is_enable = true
GROUP  BY b.NAME,b.id
```

EXPLAIN

```
   +----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                                                                       | key                         | key_len | ref                      | rows | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | range  | PRIMARY,fk_modules_organizations1,fk_modules_store_users1,sort_modules_name,wh_modules_type,new_idx | new_idx                     | 9       | NULL                     |  160 | Using index condition; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c     | ref    | fk_module_chapters_modules1                                                                         | fk_module_chapters_modules1 | 4       |         b.id             |    1 | NULL                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                             | PRIMARY                     | 4       |         b.store_users_id |    1 | Using index                           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ref    | store_users_id_UNIQUE,fk_user_modules_store_users1,fk_user_modules_modules1                         | fk_user_modules_modules1    | 4       |         b.id             |  149 | NULL                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | d2    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,fk_store_users_stores1                                                                      | PRIMARY                     | 4       |         a.store_users_id |    1 | NULL                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | e     | eq_ref | PRIMARY,Stores-Cities                                                                               | PRIMARY                     | 4       |        d2.stores_id      |    1 | Using where                           |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | f     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                             | PRIMARY                     | 4       |         e.city           |    1 | NULL                                  |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------+--------------------------+------+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename` statements for your tables. That will help us identify any incorrect datatypes and see what indexes you do have. Also, is the `IN` always just 3 values, or does it vary? Where do those values from come? (ie user input, or a previously run query, etc)

Comment: Hi thanks for taking a look into my query. IN always have just 3 values (1,2,4). SHOW CREATE TABLE details for 5 tables are soo large. pls tell me if u need SHOW CREATE TABLE for any particular table. thnks

Comment: You aren't getting any responses because you aren't providing clear information. Provide all the SHOW CREATE TABLE statements, and unless you are being forbidden by your employer, or similar, from doing so, correct your query to show the actual table and column names, instead of these fake names. It helps with our understanding and reduces the risk of you making a mistake when editing the names. We can deduce most of the names anyway, from the `*_id` columns and the keys in the EXPLAIN statement.

Answer (score 0):

This may help some:

```
INDEX(organizations_id, is_enable, type) -- on b
```

Since you say `COUNT(DISTINCT...)`, it smells like the `JOINs` are exploding the number of rows, then you are `DISTINCTifying` them back to where they ought to be.  One way to see that is to do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... JOIN ...` without a final `GROUP BY`.  If that is a number much bigger than any table size, then you have this classic problem.

Sometimes the solution is to replace a `JOIN` by

```
SELECT  ...,
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM x ... )  AS x_ct,  -- instead of `JOIN x`
        ...
```